# Error in using CSV, itertools, and operator to crawl a directory and slice csv files

Tags: python

I am getting an error:  fieldnames = csv_readers.fieldnames
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'fieldnames'

so i comment out the line, run again.

new error: sorted_csv_contents = sorted(csv_contents, key = op.itemgetter(0))
AttributeError: DictReader instance has no attribute '**getitem**'

Purpose of the code: to slice a csv file by column values, grouping each unique instance along with its duplicates into a new file. All of this having been done without having to enter an actual filepath every time.

```
from os import listdir
import csv
import itertools as it, operator as op

# Get the list of all files/directories in current path
all_files = listdir('.')

# Filter out only the .csv files
csv_files = [file for file in all_files if file.endswith('.csv')]

print csv_files

# Create file objects and csv objects for each CSV
csv_contents =[]
file_objects = [open(file) for file in csv_files]
csv_readers = [csv.DictReader(csvfile) for csvfile in file_objects]
fieldnames = csv_readers.fieldnames
for line in csv_readers:
csv_contents.append(line)

sorted_csv_contents = sorted(csv_contents, key = op.itemgetter(0))

for groupkey, groupdata in it.groupby(sorted_csv_contents,     key=op.itemgetter(0)):
with open('slice_{:s}.csv'.format(groupkey), 'wb') as fou:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(fou, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(groupdata)

for file in file_objects:
file.close()
```

Comment: `csv_readers` is created as a list, maybe you should look at its elements ?

Comment: In general, try not to just comment out the line producing the error.  Python errors are meant to be readable, so try and actually read through them to solve the problem.  `csv_readers` is a `list` object.  It looks like you wanted to access the "fieldnames" attribute on a csv.DictReader object.

Comment: ok so something like :  for element in csv_readers(): print element[1]

Comment: No, because that would call `csv_readers`, but `csv_readers` is a list, not a function.